# Schedule a job to run after 30 seconds using Django-rq

Tags: django, django-rq

I'm trying to implement the `django-rq` since I have some scraping that sometimes fails and has to be scheduled to run again after, say, 30 seconds.

As far as I understand, I push a job the queue by

```py
django_rq.enqueue(scrape_func, foo, bar=baz)
```

is there a way to push it to the queue and give it

1. A timestamp to run (like Airflow) e.g `0 01 * * *`

or

2. a time-delay before run (e.g 30 sec)

Answer (score 0):

From the README on the [GitHubPage](https://github.com/rq/django-rq#support-for-scheduled-jobs):

> With RQ 1.2.0. you can use built-in scheduler for your jobs. For example:

```py
from django_rq.queues import get_queue

queue = get_queue('default')
job = queue.enqueue_at(datetime(2020, 10, 10), func)
```